# How to Convert DateTime?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, parsing, windows-phone-7

I am currently pulling start times from an XML file and using a date checking method to filter and then display in a Listbox.Itemsource.

Currently the start times are in "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz" format in my XML file and my DateChecking method is also the same format for comparison to work.

What I would like to do is to convert the format from "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz" to Long format "Wednesday 19th June 12:00 PM and have this display in the listbox.

The Code #######################################################

```
namespace TV_Guide_Version2
{
    public partial class TV2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public TV2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadStringCompleted);
            c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.Domain.com/XMLSrouce.xml?"));

        }

        bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
            DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);

            return (now.AddHours(-2) <= otherDate && otherDate <= now.AddHours(24));
        }


        void c_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;


            var r = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);



            listBox1.ItemsSource = from tv in r.Root.Descendants("programme")
                                   where tv.Attribute("channel").Value == "1201"
                                   where MyDateCheckingMethod(tv.Attribute("start").Value)
                                   let channelE1 = tv.Attribute("channel")
                                   let startE1 = tv.Attribute("start")
                                   let nameEl = tv.Element("title")
                                   orderby tv.Attribute("start").Value ascending
                                   let urlEl = tv.Element("desc")


                                   select new TV1guide



                                   {
                                       DisplayName = nameEl == null ? null : nameEl.Value,
                                       ChannelName = channelE1 == null ? null : channelE1.Value,
                                       ChannelURL = urlEl == null ? null : urlEl.Value,
                                       StartTime = startE1 == null ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(startE1.Value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal),



                                   };



        }

        public class TV1guide
        {
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string ChannelURL { get; set; }
            public string ImageSource { get; set; }
            public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
            public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
            public string ChannelName { get; set; }

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Everything appears to be in working order.

Comment: My Question is " How do I convert to Long date format?" I thought that was pretty clear.

Comment: A down arrow? I think thats a bit harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do the trick:

```
var input = "20110901070000 +1100";
var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
var longFormat = dateTime.ToString("D");
```

Using `DateTimeOffset` makes it easier when working with times in different timezones.

**EDIT**:

I think there are two problems we are trying to solve here, if I am not mistaken. Let's break it down:

1. We want to parse a Date/Time for purposes of displaying cleanly.
2. We want to filter by that Date/Time to display only certain records.

I think the first bit is to make sure we get all of the information into a correct data type. Something like this:

```
    var data = 
        from tv in r.Root.Descendants("programme")
        where tv.Attribute("channel").Value == "1201"
        let channelE1 = tv.Attribute("channel")
        let startE1 = tv.Attribute("start")
        let nameEl = tv.Element("title")
        orderby tv.Attribute("start").Value ascending
        let urlEl = tv.Element("desc")
        let guide = new TV1guide
        {
            DisplayName = nameEl == null ? null : nameEl.Value,
            ChannelName = channelE1 == null ? null : channelE1.Value,
            ChannelURL = urlEl == null ? null : urlEl.Value,
            StartTime = startE1 == null ? (DateTimeOffset?)null : ParseDate(startE1.Value),
        }
        where DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(-2) <= guide.StartTime && guide.StartTime <= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1)
        select guide;
}

private static DateTimeOffset ParseDate(string value)
{
    return  DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

Now, if you wanted, you could introduce another property on `TV1guide` that displays it the way you'd like:

```
public string StartTimeDisplay {get { return StartTime.HasValue ? StartTime.Value.ToString("D") : ""; }}
```

Or if you feel that it is too odd putting it there, you can place it whereever you'd like. THe point being now that it has been parsed into the `TV1guide`, you can display it however you need to when the time comes.

Comment: Thanks for that. Im still not sure how I can work it into my current code for the date comparison

Comment: @Rhys: What is the purpose of "Checking it"? To make sure it is within a certain range? I'll update with more details.

Comment: The checking to to display listings based on current time. and disaply + - hours . So, it will look for results with the current start time and display that plus listings from 2 hours previous and 12 hours ahead.

Comment: @Rhys:  It seems to me that this actually answers the question you had be explicit asked to express to which you said: "How do I convert to Long date format?".  However I don't think that is at all what you are after since you already know that, .ToString("D").  Consider adjusting your question to clear identify what it is that you are stuggling with, that is how do you compare DateTimes from different timezones?   The answer of course is here in this answer as well __use DataTimeOffest__ instead of a plain `DateTime`.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Yes, I believe my question as misunderstood. Probably due to me not explaining it well. Although it was editing and change by someone, from the original question which happens quite a bit. I will reword it and hope that it doesn't get edited again.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I have updated the code and the question. Hopefully what I am trying to achieve is clearer now.

Comment: @Rhys: I've updated my answer. Sorry, we lost power during a hurricane and we just got it back.

Comment: @vcsjone Hope the hurricane isn't to bad. Thanks for your answers, but it doens't work, ParseDate isn't a method and it tries to covert to string when it shouldn't. Also, I dont see where your code ouputs to listbox.Itemsource?